# Swift CLLocationManager(didUpdateLocations) is called too often

Tags: swift, delegates, mapkit, core-location, cllocationmanager

Can anyone explain, why the delegated method 'CLLocationManager(didUpdateLocations)' is called for 4 times although I immediately stop updating? I need the current location only once :)

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

class ContactView: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    let clLocationManager = CLLocationManager()

    var latitude: AnyObject = 0.000000
    var longitude: AnyObject = 0.000000

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.nameTextField.delegate = self
        clLocationManager.delegate = self
        clLocationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        clLocationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        clLocationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(manager.location!, completionHandler: {
            (placemarks, error) -> Void in
            self.clLocationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
            if placemarks!.count > 0 {
                self.latitude = (manager.location?.coordinate.latitude)!
                self.longitude = (manager.location?.coordinate.longitude)!
                print(self.latitude)
                print(self.longitude)
            } else {
                print("Error")
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to move the stopUpdatingLocation outside from reverseGeocodeLocation

```
 func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    manager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(manager.location!, completionHandler: {
                (placemarks, error) -> Void in
                if placemarks!.count > 0 {
                    self.latitude = (manager.location?.coordinate.latitude)!
                    self.longitude = (manager.location?.coordinate.longitude)!
                    print(self.latitude)
                    print(self.longitude)
                } else {
                    print("Error")
                }
            })
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your code like the following:

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    manager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(manager.location!, completionHandler: {
        (placemarks, error) -> Void in
        if placemarks!.count > 0 {
            self.latitude = (manager.location?.coordinate.latitude)!
            self.longitude = (manager.location?.coordinate.longitude)!
            print(self.latitude)
            print(self.longitude)
        } else {
            print("Error")
        }
    })
}
```

You're seeing the problem because you're continuing to update your location while the call to reverse geocode your location is still happening.